# source.list.d and source.list error on update Ubuntu 18.04.3

Tags: apt, 18.04, package-management, updates

This is what I get after deleting the source.list.d after reading a forum online about my update error. Initially it gave --add key...-- error.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Reading package lists... Done
W: Unable to read /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ - DirectoryExists (2: No such file or directory)
W: Unable to read /etc/apt/sources.list - RealFileExists (2: No such file or directory)
```

Comment: Try to manually create the missing `sources.list.d` directory by running `sudo mkdir /etc/apt/sources.list.d`.